# Why READ & WRITE curl callback are not called?

Tags: php, curl

I have a curl request that run on PHP. I want to know all in/out to check for latency on TCP connection made over HTTP. If I run a curl in command line, it will never stop as it's not a download request but a TCP connection. The objective of this TCP isn't to just exist, but to simulate a real specific software that will do the same (but with more content). I want to know the data **during the connection, and not at the end**.

I found in [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) both callback `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` & `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` that could help. Actually, they are not called, only `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` is called fine.

```php
$output = "tmp-output.txt";
$startime =  time();
$head = ['Connection: Keep-Alive','Keep-Alive: 60'];
$targetFile = fopen("/opt/test/" . $output, 'w+');
$ch = curl_init($var);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $user);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $head);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, function($resource, $stream, $maximum) {
    // not called
    $fn = "/opt/test/test.txt";
    file_put_contents($fn, file_get_contents($fn) . "Reading at " . time() . "(max: " . $maximum . ")\n");
});
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, function($resource, $data) {
    // not called
    $fn = "/opt/test/test.txt";
    file_put_contents($fn, file_get_contents($fn) . "Writing at " . time() . " (data: $data)\n");
    return strlen($data);
});
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION,  function ($resource, $download_size, $downloaded, $upload_size, $uploaded) {
    // called
});

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, 1024);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $targetFile);
curl_exec($ch);
fclose($targetFile);
```

The file `/opt/test/test.txt` stay empty even if it can be written (permission given & folder existing). I've got no error.

I'm well receiving data as without the `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION` callback, I have result like that:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  4179    0  4179    0     0    347      0 --:--:--  0:00:12 --:--:--   339
```

I'm running the file with like `php myFile.php`.

Why they are not called?

Comment: `// not called` - _actually_ not called, or perhaps only somehow not able to write to the file you specified? I'd make an actual debug output in those places first of all.

Comment: the code can write on the file: permission given & folder existing. But it doesn't

Comment: Quote manual: _"CURLOPT_READFUNCTION: A callback accepting three parameters. The first is the cURL resource, the second is a stream resource provided to cURL through the option CURLOPT_INFILE, [...]"_ - not seeing `CURLOPT_INFILE` being set anywhere in your code.

Comment: Is that required? I know that for `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION`, the doc said explicitly it will work only if `CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS ` is set. Also, I don't know what value set for this

Comment: Also from the manual (for `CURLOPT_READFUNCTION` ): "_The callback must return a string ..._" You don't return anything

Comment: You also have lots of useful informations available in `curl_getinfo()`, including connection timings and download/upload speed

Comment: @brombeer Even if I return anything, it should be called at least one time, then failed and maybe stop the curl/php script. Also, idk what return

Comment: @Kaddath it seems to be when the curl is finished, not during the connection is done. I'm using a TCP connection. I'll more explain in my post

Comment: @Elikill58 I see, never used CURL to do ftp connections, wouldn't it be easier with the `ftp_` functions? For CURL 2 suggestions: first you still could use `curl_getinfo()` as debug to detect if by (lack of) luck your connexion has not been terminated by any of your callback functions. Second I recommend reading the comments at the bottom of the docs about the callbacks, there are examples for them, they are not used primarly to get info, but to handle the data yourself, and if you set them, you MUST handle the data

Comment: @Kaddath I don't want to do FTP connection. The connection isn't terminated, thanks to the progress function I can know when it stop (in fact, I stop it manually only). Also, I can know thanks to the script that stop running, or that I do ctrl + C. Finally, I'll check those comments

Comment: @Elikill58 sorry my brain messed up FTP with TCP :P